# Create custom library install script in MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, installation

I'm developing a native C++ multi-platform library that runs (among other platforms) on MacOS.

I've already written a Makefile that builds the library and now I'd like to write a `make install` that will copy the binaries and header files to the "standard" locations where all other libraries reside (something similar to `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib` in Linux).

Few important points:

- I'm not using (and don't want to start using) frameworks like CMake or Homebrew, I'd like to write the installation script myself inside my Makefile
- My library compiles as static library (.a) and not dynamic library (.so). Don't know if it matters...
- I also have a basic Makefile containing external includes people should include in their Makefiles when writing application on top of my library. Is there any standard place to copy this Makefile to?

What I'm actually asking is what are the standard folders in MacOS to contain:

- Static linked precompiled binaries (.a files)
- Header files (.h files)

In Linux, for example, the standard folder is `/usr/local`. What is the equivalent folder(s) in MacOS?

Comment: Homebrew often leverages these `Makefile` installers anyway, so depending on Homebrew alone is a bad plan. Have a look at a Homebrew package that has a Makefile and see how it's done.

Comment: I tried but it's quite complex because Homebrew does a lot of other stuff. I thought someone here could guide me how to do it or point me to an article or something describing it (I googled it but couldn't find such article)

Comment: I don't know that there's a standard here. There's many, many Makefile recipies for installers. Most use some kind of `configure` script to self-generate.

Comment: There must be a standard in MacOS to where native (c/c++) libraries and header files should reside after they're installed. I'm trying to understand what is this standard. If you could point me to an installation script or a recipe where this is explained it'd be great

Comment: That's what `configure` does: It determines what compiler environment it needs to set up, where to link things, and ultimately, what `make install` should do.

Comment: So what does 'make install' do in MacOS? To which folders are binaries and header files copied to?

Comment: You'll have to examine a bunch of existing packages to see how they do it. There's so many examples it's perhaps overwhelming, but pick one at random and have a look.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. If you have recommendations on a specific package I should look into (which code is easy to follow) I'd really appreciate that

Comment: I don't know what "easy to follow" means for you, so pick one at random.

Comment: I think you want to look at Darwin/BSD standards for this not for OS X.  the OSX standards are going to be for shared library bundles in /Applications that can be run from the finders.  But the BSD community definitely does have standards for most of what you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Do you know where I can find these standards?